# Can't connect to MySQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="SITEIMPORT" %>

using System;
using System.Web;

using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;


/// <summary>
/// IMPORTS DATA FROM MYSQL TO OUR WEBSITE
/// </summary>
public class SITEIMPORT : IHttpHandler {

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {

        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";

        string connStr = "server=mysql2.DOMAINREMOVED.com;user=MYUSERNAME;database=DBNAME;port=3306;password=MYPASSWORD;";
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
        try
        {
            context.Response.Write("Connecting to MySQL...");
            context.Response.Write("efef");      
            conn.Open();
            context.Response.Write("done");           

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());

        }
        conn.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("Done.");


    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

This prints the response:

> Connecting to MySQL... efef

It doesn't say login failed, server not found, server blocked request, anything like that.  No errors.  Anyone know why "done" isn't printing out?

Comment: Can you confirm that the method is finishing the execution and not hanging on opening the connection?

Comment: @Babak, how would I do that sorry I'm a noob.

Comment: Run the code with the debugger and follow the execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably what's happening is the connection to your database is timing out for whatever reason. In the meanwhile, your page request is also timing out and therefore only reporting the output until the point where your page request timed out.

Answer (score 3):

ASP.NET has no Console.

Change `Console.WriteLine` to:

```
context.Response.Write
```

And you'll see whatever you send it. In your case, you'll see some error message.